# Ubuntu - ufw status shows inactive after reboot

Tags: server, ubuntu-18.04, firewall, ufw

Had enabled auto-restart for ufw, was working fine before, but I am not able to understand what went wrong...

> use case:

when I check `sudo ufw status`
it shows -> `Status: inactive`

Then I enable it `sudo ufw enable`
it shows -> `Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)?` I hit -> `y`
it shows -> `Firewall is active and enabled on system startup`

Then I reboot it `sudo reboot`
and after reboot when i check the ufw status again, it shows inactive.

> Tried the following things:

1. In file `lib/systemd/system/uwf.service`
   added line `After=netfilter-persistent.service`
2. In file `etc/rc.local`
   added following lines: `ufw enable` `exit 0`
3. In file `etc/ufw/ufw.conf`
   was already enabled `ENABLED=yes`

Did anyone face similar issue before?

Comment: Also tried  
`echo y | ufw enable`
`exit 0`

in `etc/rc.local`